# Change magento success page url

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I need to change the success page URL that reads

> "https://magento/index.php/checkout/onepage/success"

To be displayed as

> "https://magento/checkout/onepage/success"

I need to remove /index.php from success page

Answer (score 1):

**Login to your admin backend!**

Now go to `system->configuration`
Now from web tab expand the search engine tab and make Use `Web Server Rewrites -> Yes`.

**Also you can try this using `htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

After that clean cache and check. You can see that **index.php** will be remove from your **URL**.

**Hope this will help you. Happy learning**

Comment: I did this, /index.php has been removed from all other places except success page url

Comment: i update my answer ! So try to do the second method!

Comment: Already did both these methods